# My garage sensor beam keeps going out of alignment

Tags: garage-door

I have a standard automatic garage door with a pair of garage door sensors. One sensor has a light which registers green when the sensors are in alignment. The problem is that, once or twice a week, the sensors somehow decide they are not in alignment anymore, and I have to get out of the car, jiggle them a bit until the green light comes back on, and then go on my way. Sometimes when I jiggle the sensor the green light comes on, but then (without doing anything) it slowly fades off after 15 seconds or so. At that point, I jiggle it again and it works for another week or so. Or worse, I jiggle it so that it lights up green, get back into the car, and then it has stopped working again and I have to repeat this twice. The sensors honestly seem to allow for a fair amount of wiggle room in the setup, so I'm wondering if there could be other issues with these sensors that I could troubleshoot/fix.

Comment: The tracks may not be fastened enough so misalignment could occur. I would call the door installer to inspect and adjust.

Comment: Good idea, but there's no reason to call a professional to tighten some screws. Even springs can be handled with some precautions and knowledge.

Comment: I jammed poster putty in the seams around the attachment points on a buddy's door who had the same problem. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're pretty cheap and simple devices. Maybe yours are dirty inside or the light is getting weak.

First, be sure they're well aligned and not just on the edge of the range. Use a string pulled taut past each to achieve parallel and level.

Then, look at  cleaning them. Dust, grime, and insect nests may be clogging the lenses. You may be able to pull a screw or pop tabs apart to get inside and check things out.

Finally, buy a new pair. They're not terribly expensive. Just be sure of compatibility as there are several systems and some just won't work.